# MongoDB query in C#

Tags: mongodb

I'd like to get certain documents that match a specific clause, but don't know how to achieve that WHERE effect in relational databases. I have a simple database with words and their translations (objects with 2 fields) and use this code

```
var words = database.GetCollection<Word>("Dictionary")
```

to get them. But this gets the whole collection. What if there were thousands of records in the collection? How to get just the records I want?

Comment: According to this Quick Start guide you should be calling methods on the collection to narrow your search.  http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/CSharp+Driver+Quickstart#CSharpDriverQuickstart-Getareferencetoacollectionobject Disclaimer: I have never used MongoDB before :-)

Comment: I was thinking if i could only retrieve the records I need because this way i think i'm getting the whole collection. Or maybe this is the only way (first to get the whole collection) to get these documents?

Comment: well after reading this stuff i guess getting a "reference" to the collection doesn't mean getting all the data stored in the collection.

Comment: Correct, a GetCollection does NOT get any data at all.  It is a lightweight reference.  You can then issue Find queries on it to fetch filtered data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use regular expressions matching as below. The 'i' shows case insensitivity.

```
var collections = mongoDatabase.GetCollection("Abcd");

var queryA = Query.And(
         Query.Matches("strName", new BsonRegularExpression("ABCD", "i")), 
         Query.Matches("strVal", new BsonRegularExpression("4121", "i")));

var queryB = Query.Or(
       Query.Matches("strName", new BsonRegularExpression("ABCD","i")),
       Query.Matches("strVal", new BsonRegularExpression("33156", "i")));

var getA = collections.Find(queryA);
var getB = collections.Find(queryB);
```

For Using 'And' or 'Or' in your query, if you want to search over multiple fields.

Answer (score 1):

This assumes you have a class called Word that is modled like you collection.

```
MongoServer _server = new MongoClient(connectionString).GetServer();
MongoDatabase _database = _server.GetDatabase(database);
MongoCollection _collection = _database.GetCollection(collection);

var results = _collection.FindAs<Word>(Query.EQ("MyField","WordToFind"));
```